# node versions visible on my mac even on uninstalling it

Tags: node.js, npm, nvm

I uninstalled node from my mac but still gives me the version of node and npm on typing `npm -v` and `node -v` respectively. I am unsure if is actually deleted, but if it's not deleted then why doesn't it show in my root folder?

Comment: How did you delete it? You can run `which node` from Terminal to see where the executable is installed.

Comment: I went to the root directory and did " rm -rf "Directory_name" " for all of the files

Comment: What is "the root directory"? The directory for user `root`? That's not where executables are located.

Answer (score 2):

In order to remove "node" completely, you still need to know how you installed it.

If you installed Node using Homebrew, use this command:

```
brew uninstall --force node
```

If you installed Node using NVM, use these commands:

```
nvm deactivate
nvm uninstall <node version>
```

For example:

```
nvm uninstall v19.8.1
```

I think, after running these commands, your problem will be solved. But if you still can see the version, maybe you need to uninstall Node manually. In order to remove it manually, [click & see this website](https://mackeeper.com/blog/how-to-uninstall-node-js-on-mac/).

Comment: Great answer, good job! Still, if a portion of an external website answers the question, you should quote this portion directly in the answer (you can still have the link to the website).